# Bayes estimate with weighted square error loss

Tags: bayesian, loss-functions, decision-theory

First, let $T(x)$ be an estimator of $g(\theta)$ and assume we have a square error loss function defined as
$$L[g(\theta),T(x)]=[g(\theta)-T(x)]^2$$ 
Then the posterior expected risk of $T$ is
$$\rho_T(x)=\int_{\Theta}[g(\theta)-T(x)]^2\pi(\theta|x)d\theta$$
Since we know the fact that $E(Y-b)^2$ is minimized by $b=E(Y)$, thus 
$$T(x)=E[g(\theta)|X=x]$$
minimizes $\rho_T(x)$.

Now we want to generalize this idea to a weighted square error loss defined as
$$L^*[g(\theta),T(x)]=w(\theta)[g(\theta)-T(x)]^2$$
The solution says that the Bayes estimate now is
$$T^*(x)=\frac{E[g(\theta)w(\theta)|X=x]}{E[w(\theta)|X=x]}$$
I was wondering why is this?
Since the posterior expected risk is now as
$$\rho_T^*(x)=\int_{\Theta}w(\theta)[g(\theta)-T(x)]^2\pi(\theta|x)d\theta=E\{w(\theta)[g(\theta)-T(x)]^2|X=x \}$$
Then why this $T^*(x)$ minimize our $\rho_T^*(x)$?

Thanks~

Comment: This is Corollary 2.5.2 (page 78) in my book, [The Bayesian Choice](http://amzn.to/2kxykkw).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the simplest way to look at this phenomenon is to group the posterior density in the integrand with the weighting function (since they are both functions of $\theta$) to form a product function:

$$\rho_T^* (x) = \int_\Theta [g(\theta) - T(x)]^2 \Big( w(\theta) \pi(\theta|x) \Big) d\theta.$$

Now, this product can be considered to be the kernel of a new density (which might be an improper density for some weighting functions), which we can write as $\pi^*(\theta |x) \propto w(\theta) \pi(\theta|x)$.  Via analogy to the first result we then have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
T^*(x) 
&= \int_\Theta g(\theta) \pi^*(\theta|x) d\theta \\[6pt] 
&= \int_\Theta g(\theta) \Big( \frac{w(\theta) \pi(\theta|x)}{\int_\Theta w(\theta’) \pi(\theta’|x) d\theta’} \Big) d\theta \\[6pt] 
&= \frac{ \int_\Theta g(\theta) w(\theta) \pi(\theta|x) d\theta}{\int_\Theta w(\theta’) \pi(\theta’|x) d\theta’} \\[6pt] 
&= \frac{\mathbb{E}(g(\theta) w(\theta)|X=x)}{\mathbb{E}(w(\theta)|X=x)}. \\[6pt] 
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Comment: Great answer! This line of question, I believe, leads to an interesting notion about the Bayesian approach, I recently heard/read about this here: https://jmanton.wordpress.com/statistics/ 
Thought this might be useful for @Nan